# Mockito - right way to test a method with params

Tags: android, mocking, mockito, spy

I need your assistance please:

I have this method:

```
public class MyTestClass {

protected void foo(JSONObject result, String text){
        String userId = result.optString("name");
        mApi.sendInfo(userId, text, mListener);
    }
}
```

In Mockito I do:

```
@Test
public void whenFooIsCalledThenSendInfoGetsCalled(){
    MyTestClass testClassSpy = spy(mMyTestClass);
    JSONObject jsonOb = mock(JSONObject.class);
    when(jsonOb.optString("name")).thenReturn("something");

    testClassSpy.foo(eq(jsonOb), anyString());

    ....
    some verification....
```

The problem is, the when the foo method gets called, JSONObject result is null.
I can't seem to get this to work. I thought that if I mock the object and make it return a String once optString("name") is called, would solve this issue but it seems NPE is all I get.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not from Java world but when I look on this code snippet I'm not sure what you want to test. If you want to verify exactly what your test method suggest **`whenFooIsCalledThenSendInfoGetsCalled`** then:

1. You should create spy for `mApi`
2. You should create stub for `JSONObject result`
3. You should use real implementation of MyTestClass

So your SUT class should allow for injecting dependencies:

```
public class MyTestClass {
   private mApi;
   public MyTestClass(Api api) {
       mApi = api;
   }

   void foo(JSONObject result, String text){ /* your implementation */}
}
```

And your test method:

```
@Test
public void whenFooIsCalledThenSendInfoGetsCalled(){
    // arrange test
    Api spyApi = spy(Api.class);
    JSONObjec stub = mock(JSONObject.class);
    when(stub.optString("name")).thenReturn("something");

    MyTestClass sut = new MyTestClass(spyApi);

    // Act
    sut.foo(stub, "text");

    // Assert
    verify(spyApi , times(1)).foo(eq("something"), "text", listener);
}
```